# Eclipse won't recognize my device

Tags: android, eclipse

I searched trough many questions and couldn't find an answer that fix my problem.
I'm new on creating Android projects and I'm still getting familiarized with the eclipse platform.

To the point, when I run my project I get this error

> No compatible targets were found. Do you wish to add new Android Virtual Device?

I changed the AndroidManifest.xml from targetSdkVersion="18" to "15" (Which is my device level, Android version 4.0.4, correct me if I'm wrong)

Then I clicked on Run Configuration and switched from "Launch on all compatible devices/AVD's" to "Always prompt to pick device", and still couldn't get the project to work.

When I reverted the Run Configuration I get this output everytime I try to run the project

> [2013-12-15 21:27:28 - MyFirstApp] No active compatible AVD's or devices found. Relaunch this configuration after connecting a device or starting an AVD.

What's the meaning of both messages? How can I make it work?

Some details:
Android Version: 4.0.4
OS: Windows XP
Samsung Galaxy S DUOS

Comment: How about your `minimumSdkVersion`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to have Samsung Kies installed on your computer so you can have drivers for your device, also, from eclipse:

window -> show view -> devices

if you don't see your device here, this means either your ADB is not running, or your device is not recognized by your computer

also verify you have debug mode enabled in your device

Comment: I installed Samsung Kies, but I can't even see "devices" on Show View.  http://gyazo.com/20245d9e8a5695b0ca9b0d49e8f70658.png

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the steps

Step 1

1. Check if the device driver is installed successfully. If not, download the drivers and plug the device again.

Try this link to download the driver software - http://samsung-kies.en.softonic.com/

Step 2

1. Click Start-> Run-> CMD. (Go to command prompt)
2. Navigate to the android SDK platform tools path.
3. Type adb devices
   Now you should get the device listed and a tag "device" next to the device ID

Step 3

1. If you get "no devices found", type adb kill-server
2. Type adb start-server
3. Now type adb devices.

Now you are good to start testing your applications on device.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the usb debug driver for you device installed? This is the driver that allows your device to "comunicate"with eclipse in order to debug